# Powershell data scraping: extracting a class value

Tags: powershell, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a class value from a html page but got hooked at a point trying to parse the regex.

```
<div class="studid" idataid="studdata" cloc="studloc" processor="chat" cid="important_1" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="studid" idataid="studdata" cloc="studloc" processor="chat" cid="important_2" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="studid" idataid="studdata" cloc="studloc" processor="chat" cid="important_3" style="display:none"></div>
```

Here is my code and what I tend to get.

```
$sites = get-content "msite.txt"
foreach($site in $sites){
$request = iwr -Uri $site -UseBasicParsing
}
$cidlist = @()

foreach($object in $request.Links) {
    $object.cid
    if($object.cid -like '*[a-z,A-Z]*') {
        write-host "Found" -ForegroundColor Green
        $cidlist += $object.cid
    }
    else {
        #write-host "did not find services"
    }
    $cidlist | Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File C:\users\administrator\Desktop\cid_found.txt
}
```

I intend to get the list:
important_1
important_2
important_3

Help to get it right will be appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware that string comparison operators in PowerShell default to case-insensitivity - `-like '*[a-z,A-Z]*'` can be simplified as `-like '*[a-z,]*'`

Comment: I tried that already but it did not return anything as well.

Comment: I notice you iterate over `$request.Links`. Shouldn't it be something else, since you mean to get div's?

Comment: @palle-due Yes, I did because it is a list to urls which gets the link. However, if you could help with another working option it would be insightful. Thanks.

Comment: `-like` does not use regex, it's a wildcard operator. Did you mean `-match '^[a-z]+_\d+'` perhaps?

Comment: that data is within a cid attribute not class attribute btw. And the regex from Theo looks more like what you might be after if going down that route. However, if the start of the string is fixed, as per your example, then I would use that as part of the pattern.